# C++ Infinite looping

Tags: c++, loops

I have a problem that my program just infinite loops.
After writing in console 'Ne' or 'Ja'

// Translating in English Ne would be No and Ja would be Yes.

// The thing is that I want exit program after writing Ne. And return again to start of program if I write Ja.

// I know my code is crap, but I'm here for help.

Anyways there is a code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    {
        while (true)
        {   
        system("cls");
        cout << "Noteikt naturalo skaitlu summu intervala no A [1] lidz B   [N].\n\n";
        Sleep(850);
        cout << "Ludzu ievadiet naturalo skaitli: \n\n";
        int Naturalais, Summa = 0;
        cout << "--> "; cin >> Naturalais; cout << "\n";

        for (int i = 1; i <= Naturalais; ++i)
        {
            Summa += i;
        }
        Sleep(250);
        cout << "Summa = " << Summa; cout << "\n\n";

        char Atbilde;

        cout << "Atkartot Ievadi? (Ja = Ievadit naturalo skaitli velrezi / Ne = Ne uz Aizvert Programmu.\n\n";
        cout << "--> "; cin >> Atbilde; cout << "\n";

        if (Atbilde == 'Ne' || Atbilde == 'ne')
            return 0;
        if(Atbilde == 'Ja' || Atbilde == 'JA')
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off: `Atbilde == 'Ne'` Atbilde is a `char`. `'Ne'` is 2 chars. I'm surprised this compiles. But I doubt it is ever going to match.

Then: No matter what your answer, you always exit the loop - either via `return` or `break`. Obviously you only want to exit the loop in one of the 2 conditions.

Answer (score 1):

add header file cstring instead of string

Declare Atbilde as string
and apply

```
if (Atbilde.compare(0,2,"Ne") == 0 || Atbilde.compare(0,2,"ne") == 0)
        continue;
    if(Atbilde.compare(0,2,"Ja") == 0 || Atbilde.compare(0,2,"JA") == 0)
        break;
```